# Solving Algebraic Expressions by Simplifying: $61 u +1 -1-1-y+\frac{a y^3}{ay} + 28$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To start off, I don't know where to begin. I don't know how to solve expressions. I have the answer sheet. If you could just explain why the solution is indeed the solution, I'd appreciate it.

> Simplify
> $$61 u +1 -1-1-y+\frac{a y^3}{ay} + 28$$
> Given answer:
> $$y^2+61u-y+27$$

Comment: One does not "solve" expressions.  One may _evaluate_ expressions or _simplify_ expressions.  One may _solve_ equations or _solve_ problems.  But "solve" is the wrong word for this occasion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints:

$$\frac{a y^3}{a y} = y^2,~~~ 1-1 - 1 + 28 = 27$$

**Added in response to OP's comment**

collect all the constants. You get 27.

Eliminate common terms in fractions to get $y^2$ from $\frac{a y^3}{a y} $.

Now rewrite it in the form they want. There is nothing special about the order. That is what is given in the problem.

Comment: Thanks! But to be honest, no still don't understand. Can you please tell me in another way? For example, "Just take these terms and add them and find this." Not very good at math. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

$$61u+1-1-1-y+\frac{ay^3}{ay}+28$$

Start off by grouping like terms:

$$61u + (1-1-1+28) +\left(\frac{ay^3}{ay}-y\right)$$

Use the exponential rule: $$\frac{a^n}{a^m}=a^{n-m}$$

Note the $a$'s cancel $\left(\frac{a^1}{a^1}=a^{1-1}=a^0=1\right)$ and $\frac{y^3}{y^1}=y^{3-1}=y^2$

So the original expression becomes:

$$61u+27+y^2-y \equiv y^2+61u-y+27$$

Comment: Thanks! But to be honest, no still don't understand. Can you please tell me in another way? For example, "Just take these terms and add them and find this." Not very good at math. Thanks again.